# IConfigurationSections return empty values at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-5

I ran into a problem reading custom configuration variables.
The values are binded on debug mode but when i publish the app on linux and run it, it seems like the configuration values are always empty
here is the code that i tried.

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //Code Omitted
    // ===== Add Jwt Authentication ========\\

    var jwtAppSettingOptions = Configuration.GetSection(nameof(JwtIssuerOptions));
    if (jwtAppSettingOptions == null)
        throw new ArgumentException("jwtAppSettingOptions is not found!");
    var apsSettingValue = jwtAppSettingOptions[nameof(JwtIssuerOptions.Key)];

    //This error is Thrown during runtime on Linux
    //Meaning the Section is found but the values of each key is empty

    if (apsSettingValue == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(apsSettingValue))
      throw new ArgumentException("ApsSettings Are Not Loaded! -" + nameof(JwtIssuerOptions.Key));
}


public class Startup
{
    //public  ILogger Logger { get; }
    //IFormatter _formatter;
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }
    private string ConnectionString => Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
}
```

Appsettings.json

```
 {
   "Logging": {
   "LogLevel": {
   "Default": "Information",
   "Microsoft": "Warning",
   "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
   }
  },
 "JwtIssuerOptions": {
  "Key": "KEYHERE",
  "Issuer": "http://www.domain.test/",
  "Audience": "http://www.domain.test/web"
  },
 "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Comment: So what is the configuration source/provider you are using, where is the code.

Comment: it is just reading the appsettings.json AFAIK. This code works fine on 3.0 are there any changes on net5

Comment: Where is the code that reads that calls the configuration source that adds  appsettings.json to the ConfigurationBuilder. However my gut feeling is you just need to set the properties of the json file to copy always

Comment: already set it to Copy Always in the properties.